# How can I get the last commit date of a GitLab Repo in Python

Tags: python, git, gitlab

I'm searching a way how I get the last commit date of a Repo via Python.

```
gl.auth()
project = gl.projects.get('paulsner_lars/Test')
```

Comment: Well you have `project.commits.list()`... so that should be straightforward.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you list the commits, the most recent commit will be the first commit returned.

```
most_recent_commit, = project.commits.list(per_page=1)
print(most_recent_commit.committed_date)
```

However, keep in mind that commit dates are arbitrary and can be set by the committer. If you want to reliably know the last activity on the repo, use `project.last_activity_at` or `project.events.list` instead.